# Make a child view match the width of a parent scrollview

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have a horizontal scrollview with many EditText children. I want each of these children to be the same width of the visible area of the parent scrollview. Is this possible in XML?

Comment: Depending on your content, a ViewPager would not be more appropriate?

Comment: use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for the `edittext` and give this attribute as well `android:minWidth="80dp"` (any size which suits well) and keep separate layouts for screen sizes :)

Comment: @alex - yes a ViewPager was what I should have used. Am using it in my newer projects now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it writing a small helper class:

We are creating a very small class that extends `EditText` called `FullWidthEditText` like this:

```
package com.YOURPACKAGENAME;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;

public class FullWidthEditText extends EditText {
    public FullWidthEditText(Context context) { super(context);}    
    public FullWidthEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }
    public FullWidthEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        View parentScrollView=((View)(getParent().getParent()));

        if (parentScrollView!=null) {
            // check the container of the container is an HorizontallScrollView
            if (parentScrollView instanceof HorizontalScrollView) {
                // Yes it is, so change width to HSV's width
                widthMeasureSpec=parentScrollView.getMeasuredWidth();
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Now you have this class created, you can use it in your XML just like a normal EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff0000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.YOURPACKAGENAME.FullWidthEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/yourEditTextId">
        </com.YOURPACKAGENAME.FullWidthEditText>

        <com.YOURPACKAGENAME.FullWidthEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </com.YOURPACKAGENAME.FullWidthEditText>
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

You can also create it programmatically, add handlers, listeners, change text, findViewById ... etc ... just like a normal EditText.

```
 EditText editText=new EditText(context);
 FullWidthEditText fullWidthEditText=new FullWidthEditText(context);
```

- Note that this solution works for any other Widget as well. If you need ie. a full-width button, just change `extends EditText` for `extends Button` and you got it.
- You can easily customize the size, the key line is: `widthMeasureSpec=parentScrollView.getMeasuredWidth();` so you can ie. make full width minus 10 or 20px, make half width, etc.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I tried too use this solution for RelativeLayout but subviews not showing up.. do you have a solution?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think `ViewPager` should be more appropriate but maybe you can try this view hierarchy:

- `HorizontalScrollView` (`width = MATCH_PARENT`, **`weightSum = 1`**)

  - `LinearLayout` (`orientation = HORIZONTAL`, **`weight = 3`**, **`weightSum = 3`**)

    - `LinearLayout` (*page 1*, `orientation = VERTICAL`, **`weight = 1`**)

      - `EditText` (`width = MATCH_PARENT`)
    - `LinearLayout` (*page 2*, `orientation = VERTICAL`, **`weight = 1`**)

      - `EditText` (`width = MATCH_PARENT`)
    - `LinearLayout` (*page 3*, `orientation = VERTICAL`, **`weight = 1`**)

      - `EditText` (`width = MATCH_PARENT`)

Note: I have not tested it.

Comment: Interesting property weightsum, didn't know about it, however, this won't work for several reasons: (1) You cant assign weight/sum to the first linearlayout, as HorizontalScrollView is not a LinearLayout but a FrameLayout. (2) You'd have to wrap the first HScrollV into yet another linearlayout to be able to use weights there.. and besides the Layout processor will need 12 or 24 passes (!!!) to measure all this, LinearLayout with weights are multipass layouts and nesting them makes the situation exponentially worse !

Answer (score 0):

For your `EditTexts`, when you set `layout_width` or `height` to `match_parent`, they'll match whatever size their parent is set to. But their dimensions will expand once their content will be filled with text, hence having the same width / height than the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Although it can be done using horizontal scrollview. I have found it is much much easier to use a view pager instead. Its also cleaner and allows for a smoother swipe in my opinion.

Add the xml

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"/>
```

set the pager up

```
 mPager =(ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager .setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter());
        mPager .setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
```

Adapter

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View page= inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_item, container, false);

        TextView textView =(TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textView);


        textView.setText("Text");

        container.addView(page);
        return(page);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                            Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals( object );
    }


}
```

Comment: If the content is similar to a listview, a gridview or many views, your answer is correct. However for (just) multiple EditTexts, I don't think that create a ViewPager and (mainly) an Adapter is a save resource way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found some edge cases where the `FullWidthEditText` posted by rupps didn't work, so I modified it to work in all the cases I've found:

```
public class FullWidthTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
{
    public FullWidthTextView( final Context context )
    {
        super( context );
    }

    public FullWidthTextView( final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs )
    {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    public FullWidthTextView( final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr )
    {
        super( context, attrs, defStyleAttr );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec )
    {
        View parentScrollView = ((View) (getParent().getParent()));

        boolean needsRemeassure = false;

        if( parentScrollView != null )
        {
            // check the container of the container is an HorizontallScrollView
            if( parentScrollView instanceof HorizontalScrollView )
            {
                // Yes it is, so change width to HSV's width
                int parentWidth = parentScrollView.getMeasuredWidth();
                if( parentWidth > 0 )
                {
                    widthMeasureSpec = parentWidth;
                }
                // It's possible for the parent to still have ZERO width
                // in this case we must request to be remeassured
                else
                {
                    needsRemeassure = true;
                }
            }
        }

        super.onMeasure( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );

        setMeasuredDimension( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ),
                              View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );

        if( needsRemeassure )
        {
            post( new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    requestLayout();
                }
            } );
        }
    }
}
```