# assign width matching parent to cardviews inside horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have this xml file which has a horizontal scrollView. I want that each of the cards inside the horizontal scrollview, have width equal to the size of the screen with a padding of 20 dp on the left and right. Can anyone suggest me how to do this ? Any suggestions will be acknowledges and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
               <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/rc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/read"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cd1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="340dp"
                        android:layout_height="155dp">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/pb"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:indeterminateTint="#4D000000"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cd2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="340dp"
                        android:layout_height="155dp">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/pb1"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:indeterminateTint="#4D000000"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cd3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="340dp"
                        android:layout_height="155dp">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/pb2"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:indeterminateTint="#4D000000"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This link should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/22901751/8649647

Comment: @princessdharmy WE can't have subviews to the cardview if we use this.

Comment: If you actually want to have a flexible tweak to this, why don't you use a Recyclerview with horizontal layout.